# Difference between Battlefield 4 and Battlefield 4 Premium Edition

Tags: battlefield-4

so what's the difference between both the battlefield editions? In gamestop here in Ireland they're selling BF4 for €59.99 and BF4 Premium edition for €65.99. For the purpose of my question lets label Battlefield 4 Premium edition "BF4P". So my question to you is what does BF4P have instead of the normal one? Does it just give me premium or does it even grant me that?

Comment: Are you sure its called premium edition? Atleast in origin those prices match to battlefield 4 and battlefield 4 : digital deluxe versions?

Comment: Yes it was my fault, it wasn't premium. Premium was written on it. it was the delux edition. Case closed :L

Comment: you should change the question. Premium and Premium Editon are different things. What's Premium has been explained [Adeese's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/138631/7354). OTOH, if BF4 Premium *Edition* will be similar to BF3 Premium Edition, then most likely it will be released in some 9-10 months from now and will include base game + Premium subscription.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your prices and [info from origin](http://www.battlefield.com/battlefield-4/buy) would seem like you're talking about normal battlefield 4 and battlefield 4 digital deluxe version.

Origin states that: "Digital Deluxe Edition also includes 3 Gold Battlepacks and a BF3 Vehicle Shortcut Bundle"

BUT on an [another page in origin](https://www.origin.com/fi-fi/store/buy/76889/pc-download/bundle/digital-deluxe-edition-ANW.html) it states that you get the first expansion called china rising in the digital deluxe version and 3 gold battle packs.

battle packs are ingame unlockable items and vehicle shortcut bundle seems to unlock all the vehicle unlockables for you.

Answer (score 4):

Battlefield 4 is the base game.

[Battlefield 4 Premium](http://www.battlefield.com/battlefield-4/premium) is basically early access to all of the map packs that will be released. It includes the following:

- Early access (2 weeks) to 5 map packs
- Additional camos, paints, emblems, and dog tags
- Priority position in server queues
- Exclusive double XP events and weekly content updates
- 12 battle packs

Additionally, if you buy it on a console, it will carry over to the next gen (Xbox 360 to Xbox One, or PS3 to PS4).

Comment: It is very important to note that Premium *does not* include the base game.

Comment: But, in the store there is a Battlefield 4 base game that says premium edition :/

Comment: Battlefield 4 **Premium Edition** is the base game plus a Premium membership, as [the banner on the cover](http://images10.newegg.com/NeweggImage/productimage/79-200-877-02.jpg) reads.

Comment: I can't find much on a Battlefield 4 Premium Edition, most of it refers to Battlefield 3. Origin does have a bundle to buy both the base game and Premium, though (https://www.origin.com/en-us/store/buy/battlefield-4/pc-download/base-game/game--premium-ANW.html).

Comment: @harbichidian that's BF3.

Comment: @3ventic nvm, misread the name you were addressing to

Comment: @3ventic perfectly valid, but if OP is staring at a "BF4 Premium Edition" box, it's probably identical. I'd edit it into the original comment if not for timeouts.

Comment: @Charkz which store are you talking about?

Comment: Gamestop, I know that it had 2 different version of Battlefield one of them having premium edtion, I'm trying to ring the store now, I also know that the gamestop online store don't show it

Comment: @harbichidian: except Battlefield 4 Premium Edition does not exist yet, at best it will be released half a year from now.

Comment: @Adeese: the advantage of BF3 Premium Edition was that the price was significantly less that buying base game and premium separately, IIRC, it was just $5 more that Premium alone. OTOH, the bundle you link to offers no saving at all. But no wonder you cannot find BF4 Premium Edition, I'd expect it to appear in shops in September 2014.

Answer (score 2):

Battlefield 4 is the base game - the campaign and the multiplayer aspect. You need this to play online.

Battlefield 4 Premium does the same sort of thing as Battlefield 3 Premium - exclusive dogtags, knife, etc, with battlepacks that gives things like XP boots of 100%, 50% and 25% and access to the DLC early.

Battlfield 4 Delux edition is the game, the first DLC, and a couple of battlepacks.

I just had a look on the GameStop site and they don't appear to mention a Premium Edition.

Comment: Where did you find premium *edition*?

Comment: Mistake, it's delux edition rather than premium.

Answer (score 0):

As with BF3, preordering just gives you the first DLC free. Maybe and I repeat MAYBE they will release a Premium-all-inclusive edition (Game+Premium) for a single purchase.

BUT when BF3 was released, Premium wasn't being offered alongside the game. It became announced and available a bit later, well not a bit, like 6 months I believe July or August, because initally the Back 2 Karkand DLC (remakes of previous Battlefield maps) was being offered as a bonus for preordering the game, nobody had idea that this premium offer would be available.

My guess is, an all inclusive edition would become available like 9 - 12 after game's release, to lure new customers.
I'm gonna wait till next year (yes I have a lot of patience, and yes I don't care if everybody is miles ahead), to see if an all inclusive edition for $50-$60 becomes available and buy it at the same time as a PS4, that way, I would save between $60-$70!! (Beacuase if you buy it on current gen and want it in next gen as a digital version you pay $10 to upgrade.)

Answer (score 0):

BF4 premium edition is the full game, along with all DLC, battle packs and exclusive camos, tags etc.

BF4 premium does not come with the full game, it's like an add-on with same perks as BF4 premium edition DLC, tags, camos, except the full game.

If you have the regular BF4 you can purchase premium, it will basically be like having premium edition.

Premium edition is cheaper because it come with full game and all exclusive content, DLC, tags, camos etc.

If you are looking to buy premium you must already have the regular BF4.

Regular game $ + premium $ is more money than premium edition $.

If you are looking to buy BF4 get the premium edition because it comes with basically everything.

I was confused also but found out when I bought premium, hope it helped.